# Delegate function does not get called

Tags: ios

I have two `ViewControllers` and I'm trying to set one as the other's delegate. This is what I have:

ViewController One:

```
protocol storeChosenDelegate {
  func getPopularProductsFor(store id: String)
}

class PopularStoresVC: UIViewController {
//MARK: - Properties
var delegate: storeChosenDelegate?
private let storesView = PopularStoresView()
private let STORE_CELL = "storeCell"

fileprivate var currentStore: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        delegate?.getPopularProductsFor(store: "THIS IS WORKING NOW.")
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what I have in ViewController Two:

```
//MARK: - Properties
private let PRODUCT_CELL = "productCell"
private var popularStores = PopularStoresVC()

//MARK: - Initializers    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    popularStores.delegate = self
    setupProductsCollection()
}

extension PopularProductsVC: storeChosenDelegate {
    func getPopularProductsFor(store id: String) {
        //TODO: Show all popular products for the store's id we got.
        print("Got store \(id)")
    }
}
```

It seems that the didSet is getting called, and I do set the Second VC as the delegate, but the function just does not getting called. I have no errors or warnings related to that so I don't really understand why this is not working.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard? If yes `PopularStoresView()` is not the instance you expect. You need the **real** reference either with a segue or with instantiation.

Comment: @vadian No, I'm not using storyboard. I just removed the view part as I thought it is not relevant, sorry for not being clear enough about it.

Comment: where are you setting the currentStore value

Comment: @kjoe on scrollViewDidEndDecelerating which does not appear here, as the didSet is working.

Comment: check is delegate is not nil before call the get popularProductsForStore function

Comment: @kjoe thanks! it is nil, but what causing it to be nil and how can I fix that? I assign the second vc to be the delegate, why It turns to nil?

Comment: wich viewController come firs in the app logic, does one is shown on the screen before two, or two come out before first.

Comment: @kjoe the ViewController one is first

Comment: @kjoe Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand. the delegate is optional, so when it loads, it will be nil, but then, when the second view controller loads, it will set itself as the first one's delegate and the delegate won't be nil, am I wrong?

Comment: how do you present the second VC, must be the same instance that is property of PopularStoresVC, check where the presentation or pushing are you not creating another instance of twoViewController.

Comment: @kjoe Thank you very much! That was it.